# Undefined method 'merge' for "test":String - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a collection_select:

```
<%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :poster_id %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :feedback, :poster_id, @users, :id, @user.username, :prompt => "Select your username" %><br />
<%= f.number_field :poster_id %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This is the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for "test":String):
    15:     
    16:   <div class="field">
    17:     <%= f.label :poster_id %><br />
    18:     <%= f.collection_select :feedback, :poster_id, @users, :id, @user.username %><br />
    19:     <%= f.number_field :poster_id %>
    20:   </div>
    21:   <div class="field">
  app/views/feedbacks/_form.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_feedbacks__form_html_erb__3181571289116259961_2154876620'
  app/views/feedbacks/_form.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_feedbacks__form_html_erb__3181571289116259961_2154876620'
```

"test" is the username that was returned by `@user.username`.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the signature for collection_select is:

```
def collection_select method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}
```

i'm not sure what you're trying to do, maybe this is what you want:

```
<%= f.collection_select :poster_id, @users, :id, :username, :prompt => "Select your username" %><br />
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I am having a hard time understanding the definition of `collection_select`. Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: How do I set the default value. E.g. say I want it to automatically select the `@user.id` (assume that this has the correct value). How do I do that? I tried adding the `:default => @user.id` flag at the end, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had to think of the inputs this way to get it to make sense in my head...

collection_select ‘model field’, ‘collection of options in the dropdown menu’, ‘model field for values’, ‘model field to show in the menu’

This helped me understand