# Rails - Building a collection_select tag from a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections

I can't get my collection_select to work.. I have looked at these two links, which have conflicting syntax, and can't seem to get either to work. I've also read the Rails documentation.

[Rails 3 build a select tag with has_many belongs_to association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763963/rails-3-build-a-select-tag-with-has-many-belongs-to-association)

[Undefined method 'merge' for "test":String - Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398928/undefined-method-merge-for-teststring-rails-3-1)

I get different errors when I try the different syntax, but here is my current error.

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Models

```
class Instruction < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :exercise_id, :order, :sentence, :instruction_type_id
    belongs_to :exercise
    belongs_to :instruction_type
end

class InstructionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :instructions
    has_many :exercises, :through => :instructions
    attr_accessible :name
end
```

Instruction Controller

```
def create
    @instruction = Instruction.new(params[:instruction])
end
```

Instruction Form

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :instruction_type_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select(:instruction_type_id, @instruction_types, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select country') %>

    <%= f.label :order %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :order %>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Got it..finally..

Controller needed this defintion

@instruction_types = InstructionType.all

The controller references the class which uses camelcase, where as the model itself is written Instruction_type.